# In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions

Tags: sql

I'm new to SQL and I got this exercise for school that I need to do: "List the customer name, CD title and rating for the review (or reviews) with the highest rating".

The database has 5 tables:

```
CDTitles, Customers, Reviews, OrderLines, Orders
```

The name of the customer is in the `Customers` table (2 columns: "firstname" and "lastname"), the CD title in the `CDTitles` table has "title" and the "rating" on the Reviews table

This is what I got:

```
SELECT MAX(rating), firstname, lastname, title 
FROM Reviews, Customers, CDTitles
WHERE Reviews.customerID = Customers.customerID 
AND Reviews.catalogNumber = CDTitles.catalogNumber;
```

Although I keep getting this error: In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions. [ `Select clause = ,firstname` ].

Any help would be much appreciate it.

PS: I need to use Microsoft Webmatrix.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: that's just the way we're being taught lol, I guess my teacher is old school.

Answer (score 0):

You have used an aggregate function, but not specified the grouping.

Add a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT
    MAX(rating), firstname, lastname, title
FROM Reviews, Customers, CDTitles
WHERE Reviews.customerID = Customers.customerID
AND Reviews.catalogNumber = CDTitles.catalogNumber
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, title -- Added this line
```

---

As a matter of style, you should express the joins in the modern style:

```
SELECT
    MAX(rating), firstname, lastname, title
FROM Reviews
JOIN Customers ON Reviews.customerID = Customers.customerID
JOIN CDTitles ON Reviews.catalogNumber = CDTitles.catalogNumber
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, title
```

Comment: But that way it will select multiple rows, it's selecting all the reviews, I only want to select the one with the highest rating.
PS: thank you for the reply :)